# write list of object into tar.gz file using java language

Tags: java

i have a list of object (List) and my goal is to archive the list of the object in tar.gz file using java.
i like to use this plugin.
         
            org.codehaus.plexus
            plexus-archiver
            3.0

Comment: So.what.did.you.try?

Comment: I have a list of employe and i like to archive this  list in tar.gz file using the plexus-archiver plugin have you any idea

Comment: So you want to write a text file, wrap it in a TAR archive and compress it using gzip, is that correct?